# Bootstrap Daterangepicker time subtraction

Tags: javascript, jquery, daterangepicker, bootstrap-daterangepicker

I know daterangepicker has its function in disabling date range. But this time I need to disable time range. Specifically 12:00 AM - 1:00 PM. If I selected 11:00 AM - 2:00 PM the calculated total hours would be 2 hours stripping 1hr from the disable time range. Is this possible this picker? If not, is there a work around ? As starter, I have [this](http://jsfiddle.net/onelazy/amtxsf0x/)

```
$(function() {
    $('input[name="Date2"]').daterangepicker({
        minDate: getCurrentDateToday()+" 8:30 AM",
        dateLimit: { "days": 1},
        timePicker: true,
        timePickerIncrement: 1,
        locale: {format: 'MM/DD/YYYY h:mm A'}
    },
    function(start, end, label)
    {
        var hd = end.diff(start, 'hours');
        var md = end.diff(start, 'minutes');
        var minutesDue = md - (hd*60);
        var hoursDue = hd +"."+minutesDue;
        $('#txtTotalHrs').val(hoursDue);
    });
});
```

Comment: http://http//jsfiddle.net/onelazy/amtxsf0x/ link is not working.

Comment: sorry about that, I edited the link changed it to working one

Comment: Hey OneLazy, your issue has been resolved... check Edited Answer (put all script in to your code and try).

Comment: Thanks Soni.. I appreciate your effort. you're a life saver!

Comment: Thanks to you oneLazy, you question force me to make effort.... :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **EDITED**

```
$(function() {
  $('input[name="Date2"]').daterangepicker({
      minDate: getCurrentDateToday() + " 8:30 AM",
      dateLimit: {
        "days": 1
      },
      timePicker: true,
      timePickerIncrement: 1,
      locale: {
        format: 'MM/DD/YYYY h:mm A'
      }
    },
    function(start, end, label) {

        var breakStart = "12:00 PM" , breakEnd = "12:30 PM";

      var start_end_diff = (new Date(end) - new Date(start)) / 1000 / 60;

      var break_diff = exclude_BreakTiming(start,end ,breakStart, breakEnd);

      var total_minutes = (start_end_diff - break_diff);

      $('#txtTotalHrs').val(getTimeFromMins(total_minutes));

    });
});

function getTimeFromMins(mins) {
    // do not include the first validation check if you want, for example,
    // getTimeFromMins(1530) to equal getTimeFromMins(90) (i.e. mins rollover)
    if (mins >= 24 * 60 || mins < 0) {
        throw new RangeError("Valid input should be greater than or equal to 0 and less than 1440.");
    }
    var h = mins / 60 | 0,
        m = mins % 60 | 0;
    return moment.utc().hours(h).minutes(m).format("hh:mm");
}

function getCurrentDateToday() {
  var currentDate = new Date();
  var day = currentDate.getDate()
  var month = currentDate.getMonth() + 1;
  var year = currentDate.getFullYear();
  var fullDate = month + "/" + day + "/" + year;
  return fullDate;
}

function exclude_BreakTiming (StartTime , EndTime, BreakStart, BreakEnd){
    StartTime = Date.parse('01/01/2011 ' +StartTime.format('h:mm A'));
  EndTime = Date.parse('01/01/2011 ' +EndTime.format('h:mm A'));

  var breakStart = Date.parse('01/01/2011 '+BreakStart);
  var breakEnd = Date.parse('01/01/2011 '+BreakEnd);

    if((StartTime <= breakEnd) || ((StartTime < breakStart) && (EndTime > breakEnd)))
  {
    return ((breakEnd - breakStart) /1000 /60);
  }else{
    return 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: InBreakTime is always false why is that ? or am I overlooking on something ? here's an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/amtxsf0x/2/

Comment: as per your update no need to take `var breakEnd = moment("12:59 PM", "h:mm A");' keep it as it is... and try. InBreakTime will be true if you select Time range `11:00 to 2:00` it will give total hrs `2.6` after deduct your breaktime hr...

Comment: sir I tried selecting 02/10/2017 8:30 AM - 02/10/2017 3:30 PM but it keeps returning 7.0 its not stripping 1hr

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate it!

Comment: `if(StartTime is less than BreakStartTime && EndTime Time grater than BreakEndTime){
       InBreakTime = true;
      }`

Comment: in this way you can get if the time is include your break Time or not ; after than deduct 1hr from total time(if its true). *(i am unable to implement it right now as have some work but this is a way you can get the result)*

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135351/discussion-between-soni-vimal-and-onelazy).